# how to kill a cmd run windump.exe using Java

Tags: java, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I am trying to invoke a utility windump.exe from Java and kill it after some time (when its usage is over).

But, I am not sure how to kill it from Java Code. I have tried `process.destroy()` and sending `Ctrl C` (`char 3`) to process that started it, but none of this is working. 
I tried with Runtime as well as `ProcessBuilder` to invoke and Kill the process but the result is same.

I have just started using Java, any suggestion will be of great help. Is this a limitation that Java does not support? Or what is the way of killing a binary started in `cmd` from Java code?

I am using JavaSE1.6 and jre6 in windows 7. The following is the code snippet.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c start D:\\windump.exe -s 0 -i 5 -A -w D:\\vne.pcap");
Process WinDumpProc = null;
WinDumpProc = pb.start();

Thread.sleep(3000);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(WinDumpProc.getOutputStream())); 

out.write((char)3);
out.flush();
WinDumpProc.destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are creating a process for cmd that will itself create a child process for windump.exe.
Start directly windum.exe instead.